# loadNibNamed:owner:options crashing app after conversion to ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm having what I'm sure is a stupid issue after converting my project to ARC. This method has started crashing on the first line:

```
- (MyView*) loadMyView
{
    NSArray* elements = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:nil options:nil];

    return (MyView*)[elements objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

This worked fine before the conversion to ARC. The app crashes in the simulator with the following message:

```
[CFArray release]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Well, after sleeping on it I decided to just delete the Nib and start over to see if that helped and sure enough, it works now. I don't know what the conversion to ARC did to cause this issue but deleting the Nib and recreating it from scratch solved the problem.

Comment: Got the same problem, removing and starting over worked ! -_-

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `owner:` parameter from `nil` to `self`

```
NSArray* elements = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
```

I'm guessing because you are setting the owner to nil, your array is being created with a retain count of zero, and is therefore being deallocated right away.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help. Same crash.

Comment: can anyone tell me what does mean owner there?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It usually happens if you have inconsistencies in your nib file. In mine I had some buttons that were still connected through IBOutlets to some objects that I deleted in the header file. Hope this helps.